# epileptic dog hind legs always shake

Tags: dogs

My sister's dog has epilepsy. She won't consider medication since attacks only happen once every month or two. She doesn't see a point testing drugs if we can't see if they're working, since the dog has seizures so rarely. However, I noticed that his hind legs shake all the time. I thought it was because he was cold or excited, but he shakes all the time. The seizures happen every couple of weeks, but his hind legs are always shaking. What could this possibly mean?

Comment: Technically speaking, medication should probably be considered regardless as a safety measure.